# Which javascript interpreter is the easiest to embedd in a C application?

Tags: javascript, c, scripting, embedded-language

There are a few available and i want to support many platforms so i guess V8 isn't that good unless someone has written an interpreter patch for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScriptCore (the WebKit JS engine) has a pure C API that has guaranteed API and ABI stability -- you can build from source available at http://webkit.org but it's a system framework on macos, and is distributed at least in debian (-unstable?).  It runs on all platforms as it has both an interpreter and a jit (which is stable on x86 and x86-64)

Answer (score 2):

How about [Spidermonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/), since it's written in C?